# Cordova device loading some times

Tags: cordova, device

I'm using the Cordova device plugin to get the `device.platform`. 
But it work's just some times?! I can't understand why. It is the same code.

```
function checkDevice() {
    if(device.platform){  //Line 163
        var devicePlatform = device.platform;
        if (devicePlatform == "iOS") { // iOS
            loadDeviceIOS();
        }
    }
}
```

> 04-15 15:28:11.129: D/CordovaLog(15057):
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 163 : Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: device is not defined

At first call the plugin works well. Secont and third times get the error. Than works again. Unexplainable for me ... Please help me out ..

Comment: Have you added the `device` plugin? `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` will add it.

Comment: show me the line where you called checkDevice()

Comment: I'm guessing it has been called before device ready function in fired

Comment: @AtanuCSE, that could be. In that case, @Erdem, have you added something like: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyFunction, false);`? And then a call to `checkdevice` from the deviceReady's function.